# How to use java notify correctly in blocking queue implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, blockingqueue

I am trying to understand Java multi-threading constructs, and I am trying to write a simple implementation of blocking queue. Here is the code I have written:

```
  class BlockingBoundedQueue<E>
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        BlockingBoundedQueue(int size)
        {
            fSize = size;
            fArray = (E[]) new Object[size];
//            fBlockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<E>(size);
        }

        BlockingQueue<E> fBlockingQueue;

        public synchronized void put(E elem)
        {
            if(fCnt==fSize-1)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Should I be waiting/locking on the shared array instead ? how ?
                    wait();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Waiting thread was interrupted during put with msg:",e);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fArray[fCnt++]=elem;
                //How to notify threads waiting during take()
            }
        }


        public synchronized E take()
        {
            if(fCnt==0)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Should I be waiting/locking on the shared array instead ? how ?
                    wait();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Waiting thread was interrupted during take with msg:",e);
                }
            }

            return fArray[fCnt--];
            //How to notify threads waiting during put()
        }
        private int fCnt;
        private int fSize;
        private E[] fArray; 

    }
```

I want to notify threads waiting in Take() from put() and vice versa. Can someone please help me with the correct way of doing this.

I checked the java.utils implementation and it uses Condition and ReentrantLocks which are a little complex for me at this stage. I am okay of not being completely robust[but correct] for the sake of simplicity for now.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, call `notifyAll()` where you have the comments  `//How to notify threads waiting during take()`

Now for the more complete answer...

*The* reference to read is : [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601). The answer to your question is in there.

However, to briefly answer your question: in Java, threads synchronize by locking on the same object and using `wait()` and `notify()` to safely change state. The typical *simplified* flow is:

1. Thread A obtains a lock by entering a `synchronized` block on a lock object
2. Thread A checks some condition in a loop, if not "OK to go" call `thread.wait()`, which is a blocking call that "releases" the lock so other code synchronized on the same lock object can proceed
3. Thread B obtains the *same* lock and may do something that changes the condition thread A is waiting for. When it calls `notifyAll()`, thread A will wake up and recheck the condition and (may) proceed

Some things to remember about synchronization are:

- it is about keeping state of objects consistent by making changes to state *atomic*. "Atomic" means the entire change (e.g. to multiple fields) is guaranteed to complete (no partial, and therefore inconsistent, changes)
- it is cooperative - code synchronized on a given lock object has in common the state that is being changed and the conditions that allow that state change - you `wait` and `notify` about the same "subject". Each part of state should be guarded by its own lock object - usually a private field, e.g. `private Object lock = new Object();` would be fine
- methods that are synchronized use `this` as the lock object - doing this is easy but potentially expensive, because you are locking for *every* call, instead of just when you need to
- static methods that are synchronized use the Class object as the lock object

Comment: thnkx Bohemian for the explanation.. I still have few questions ..in my wait statements, which object is it locking on and why is same lock being acquired by wait statements in 2 different methods? Also, when you say checks some condition in a loop .. which condition is the thread checking in a loop ? .. after calling notifyAll .. would all the threads move on ?

Comment: Thanks to @Will for removing the illegal link to the book and replacing it with a clean one.

Comment: I was wondering if this was some kind of a phishing attack :) , then thought the answer is detailed and Bohemian has reputations so it should be some error ..